# Django - Flagging a single object among a set in a model

Tags: django, django-models

How do I introduce a field in a model that would flag only a single item among a set? The ideal way is to have a radio button, but radio_fields has to point to a ForeignKey or choices while what I'm looking for is simply a Boolean field. For instance:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # fields

class B(models.Model):
    a       = models.ForeignKey(A)
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This would work if I could restrict `primary` to be `True` for only one item for the objects related to `A`.

**If the above does not make sense:** I want only one item to be `True` from a set of `B` items that share the same `A`.

**UPDATE:**
I have extended this question and made a new post:
[Django - Map a OneToOneField to radio buttons on the admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199772/django-map-a-onetoonefield-to-radio-buttons-on-the-admin-interface) based on the answer I got from this question.

Comment: You could try overriding the widget for your boolean field to use a radio instead of a checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you should add a `OneToOneField` field in A:

```
class A(models.Model):
    true_b = models.OneToOneField('B', related_name='is_true')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.true_b not in self.b_set.all():
            raise ValueError('True_b has to be among those B that refer to this A')
        super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...
```

Also add a `save()` method to check if `A.true_b` is in `A.b_set` items and raise exception if it's not. You can add a shortcut method to B:

```
    @property
    def is_true(self):
        return a.true_b == self
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after, however, trying to see it work another problem appeared, now since `A` is referencing `B` in: `true_b = models.OneToOneField(B, reverse_name='is_true')` and `B` is referencing `A` in: `a = models.ForeignKey(A)`, `A` is raising: `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`

Comment: Write it in quotes: `...Field('B', ...`

Comment: This is working nicely, you probably meant `related_name` though in `true_b = models.OneToOneField('B', reverse_name='is_true')`. One thing though, in the admin interface a drop down list is generated of all the entries in B. I know the validation you put will take care of the relations, however, isn't there a way to generate a list of only the items related to A? Better yet, instead of having a drop down list, is it possible to utilize `true_b` in `A` to have radio buttons against `B` entries in the admin interface that would indicate `true_b` value?

Comment: Right, related_name. I think admin interface is customizable, so it should be possible by overriding some class.