# Django - Map a OneToOneField to radio buttons on the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following:

```
class A(models.Model):
    true_b = models.OneToOneField('B', related_name='is_true')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.true_b not in self.b_set.all():
            raise ValueError('True_b has to be among those B that refer to this A')
        super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...
    @property
    def is_true(self):
        return a.true_b == self
```

This will generate a drop down list in the admin interface for `true_b` having **all** the items in `B`, and the validation will make sure the selected item is actually referring back to `A`.

Instead of having a drop down list in the admin interface, how can I have radio fields against each entry in `B` that will map the selected item to `true_b` value?

This way it will be easier to choose the item (instead of looking up it's name and selecting from the drop down list), and the user will not be able to choose any item that does not belong to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own form for this model and pass it to admin class

```
class MyAdmin()
    class Meta()
        form=MyFormForAdmin
```

Comment: Is it possible to just make this specific change for `true_b` without having to rewrite the entire form for the model?

Comment: You don`t have to rewrite entire form, try to create ModelForm, and in init method change widget of the field. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/